# Import graphML created via gremlin in Orientdb to include in DSE graph by Graphloader

Tags: datastax-enterprise, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

I have imported my graphdata in form of GraphMl from orientDb by using gremlin console by g.saveGraphML(filename.xml) funtion.
Now I have to import this graphML in DSE graphloader .
But I found out that the format of graphML DSE graph accepts is not the same as label, member_id, community_id needs to be included which I don't see in my graphml structure.

Kindly help me in this problem as I don't want to manually change all entries in my graphML because its quite huge.

-Varun

Comment: Are you getting an error when you try to read the GraphML?

Comment: yes .. It is giving some error which signifies that the parameters are not matching .. Obviously in my GraphMl exported from orient db does not contain label and some format that DSE is expecting...

Comment: I just realized from Jason's answer below (and from re-reading your question) that you are using TinkerPop 2.x. Perhaps you should try to use this migration approach instead: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_tinkerpop2_data_migration

Answer (score 0):

Try out this XSLT transform to convert from TP2 GraphML (used by OrientDB) to TP3 GraphML (used by DSE Graph).

https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/pull/501/files

Comment: Thanks . But this is giving error while transforming. I have used this site to transform my Graphml. http://codebeautify.org/xml-xsl-transformation

Comment: I tested it out using the Gremlin Console with the code found here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-1608